# What permission needed to view salesforce integration option in exact target

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am connecting exact target with salesforce but didn't see "salesforce integration" option. 
Is there any permission needed for this[image]

I have admin permission in ET but still I cant see salesforce integration option. I have installed v5 connector in my salesforce sandbox and performed all the step mentioned in connector guide. Now while performing remaining steps in ET side i can't see this option. So what are the possible permission or issues which is causing this problem. There is not much information available in exact target site.

Answer (score 1):

You are either looking in the wrong place or the v5 Connector is not provisioned on your Marketing Cloud account. I'm not sure what Edition of Marketing Cloud you are using, but it's a chargeable option on some editions.

You can confirm if the Connector is provisioned in Marketing Cloud by following the steps below:

1. Select **Email** from the Email Studio menu in Marketing Cloud
2. Click on the **Admin** tab on the top black ribbon
3. Under Account Settings, you should see 'Salesforce Integration' option. If you don't, then you don't have the v5 Connector provisioned. Refer to screenshot below for clarification.

[image: menu]